# If $(\mathbb F,V,+)$ is a vector space and $v\in V$, can we say that $v\in(\mathbb F, V,+)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, soft-question

If $(\mathbb F,V,+)$ is a vector space and $v\in V$, can we say that $v\in(\mathbb F, V,+)$ or is that problematic with the definition of a "structure"?

We call it a 'vector space' after all, so one would presume that vectors are their elements. One could say that this structure is only a relationship or property defined on the set $V$, an organizing function on $V$, or a space that can be filled with vectors, but I think intuitively that $V$ is inherently an element of any organization imposed on it (as $V$ must be amenable to that structure, for starters). This would mean that all element in $V$ are either in the structure constructed with $V$, or in an element of that structure, I would argue. I know this may be getting on the border of objectivity here, but this question naturally developed after I posed it.

This is basically the same question as whether $\mathbb R=(\mathbb R,+,\cdot,\le)$ or $\mathbb N=(\mathbb N,S)$ (where $S$ is the successor-function) for example.

Comment: Yes. Simple as that. The underlying set is $V$ and $v\in V$ is an element of it. One wouldn't say $v\in (\mathbb{F},V,+)$ as this is not a set. You could write $v\in V=(\mathbb{F},V,+)$ in which the last equality sign resolves the abbreviation $V$ as a vector space $(\mathbb{F},V,+).$ So one is a set, $V,$ and one is a structure $(\mathbb{F},V,+),$ a vector space. But a vector is part of a set on which a structure is defined.

Comment: But since $a=b$ implies $b=a$ you're actually saying that you can say that $v\in(\mathbb F,V,+)=V$ ànd cannot say that $v\in(\mathbb F,V,+)$. Sorry but that is a plain contradiction.

Comment: Thanks to you giving me the name of this type of thing (one would expect it to be taught in a linear algebra course but no...) I found on Wikipedia that a structure *is* a set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure .

Comment: I distinguish between a set, and the structure on it. $v\in V$ doesn't say anything about $V$ other than it is a set. Already the use of the letter is a convention indicating a vector space. The structure, however, should be written as $(\mathbb{F},V,+)$ especially if I think of the uncountable occasions when people assumed $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ without mention. But now we run into the next problem. $v\in (\mathbb{F},V,+)$ is really inconvenient, and it doesn't tell us whether $v$ is a vector or a scalar. Should we write $(1,v,+)\in (\mathbb{F},V,+)$ instead? We identify set and structure.

Comment: Ok I understand the distinction. It's like the distinction between the atoms $a\in G$ that can be arranged as glass and the structuring with those atoms of the glass "$(G,p)$" (where $p$ are the properties of the glass). I see though how this could end in a discussion about whether that particular structure on $G$ is then equivalent to these particular atoms structured so (then $a\in(G,p)$), or whether the atoms are given an ideal structure (then $a\in G$ and $(G,p)$ exists), and that's not the point here, but it is a valid point I think that this is up for discussion. Do you agree?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to say. Consider the real numbers $\mathbb{R}.$ We have $0\in \mathbb{R}$ as an element of the set. But real numbers can also be a group, a ring, a field, a vector space, a differential manifold, a line, or an algebra. It is always $0\in \mathbb{R},$ an element of the set. However, if we consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a group, $0\in \mathbb{R}$ suddenly becomes the neutral element of addition, in the field $\mathbb{R}$ the only element without a multiplicative inverse, and on the line $\mathbb{R}$ an arbitrary point we marked to distinguish left and right.

Comment: The question is whether the set $X$ is inherent to the structure $(X,p)$ with features $p$, or whether the fact that $(X,p)$ is a structure merely says that $X$ is amenable to the structure with properties $p$. But even in the latter case you're really saying that the elements of $X$ can be organized into a structure with properties $p$. Saying that $(X,p)$ *is* a structure, implies that properties $p$ imposed on all the elements of $X$ *is* that structure (where the elements *with* these properties are part of the structure). A vector space is also defined as a set.

Comment: You can compare set and structure with person and role. I am a person in the set of members on SE. Currently, I am in the role to answer you. That doesn't change the person I am, nor does it prevent me from having other roles. If you consider me a member of SE or a participant in this thread is not important. It's just two different ways to address me. There is basically no difference between $V$ and $(\mathbb{F},V,+).$ If at all, then you could make a difference between set and vector space. But the latter requires a former, at least $\{0\}.$

Comment: I feel like we're talking past each other. And you first said that "yes" you can write $v\in(\mathbb F,V,+)$, then said that "one wouldn't say that", then that you can write "$V\in V=(\mathbb F,V,+)$, then that you distinguish between structure and set, and now you say that there is no difference between $V$ and $(\mathbb F,V,+)$? I'm sorry but I can't follow that. There's an answer on my question now which may help...

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, but it will not mean what you'd like it to mean, at least not without abusing notation.

Let's take the following definitions: $$(a,b) := \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\},$$ $$(a,b,c) := ((a,b),c) = \{\{(a,b)\},\{(a,b),c\}\}.$$

Applied to $v\in(\mathbb F, V, +)$, it would mean that $v = \{(\mathbb F,V)\}$ or $v = \{(\mathbb F, V),+\}$.

Of course, you can say explicitly that you will use notation $v\in (\mathbb F, V, +)$ to mean $v$ is a vector in a vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb F$, however the simple $v\in V$ already does that, since $V$ is required to be a set and we call its elements vectors.

Note that defining vector space as ordered triple is rather a technical thing, since  if we want to work within ZFC set theory, which most of us does, everything is a set, so we encode structure as a particular set. However, I'd say that most mathematicians are only working within ZFC in spirit, but often just don't bother with the full formalism, being satisfied with the knowledge that it can be done in principle. So, most would simply say something like "Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb F$."

The point is, formalism is important, but so is clear communication. Being overly formal or adopting heavy notation when it's not really necessary can actually impede communication.